# I have a weather plugin that outputs in a weird way

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Like this: https://ghostbin.co/paste/ohsuar

I only need the current temperature value. How do I get it?

Let's say that "weatherObject" is the variable with the object. I have already tried     "weatherObject.current.temperature" and it outputs "undefined".

```
[
  {
    "location": {
      "name": "New York, NY",
      "lat": "40.713",
      "long": "-74.007",
      "timezone": "-4",
      "alert": "",
      "degreetype": "C",
      "imagerelativeurl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/"
    },
    "current": {
      "temperature": "14",
      "skycode": "27",
      "skytext": "Cloudy",
      "date": "2021-05-02",
      "observationtime": "03:00:00",
      "observationpoint": "New York, NY",
      "feelslike": "15",
      "humidity": "40",
      "winddisplay": "16 km/h Southwest",
      "day": "Sunday",
      "shortday": "Sun",
      "windspeed": "16 km/h",
      "imageUrl": "http://blob.weather.microsoft.com/static/weather4/en-us/law/27.gif"
    },
...
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many Objects in your weatherObject-array. So you have to call it with the index of the array-element you want to get. Furthermore the keys of the nested objects are strings so you can't call it with the dot-notation. You have to use square brackets.

For the first element of the array it would be:

```
weatherObject[0]["current"]["temperature"]
```

**Working example:**

```js
var weatherObject = [
  {
    "current": {
      "temperature": "14"
    }
  }
];

console.log(weatherObject[0]["current"]["temperature"]);
```

Comment: that outputs an error

Comment: I overlooked that the keys are strings, so the dot-notation is useless and you have to use square brackets. See my updated answer...